# Делаю клиент на Android

Tags: java, android, android-sdk, android-studio, activity

Всем доброго времени суток. Помогите, пожалуйста, с клиентом. Есть первое активити, типа аутентификация (ввести логин, пароль и нажать ВХОД) и другие активити. Я с первого активити делаю конект к серверу в новом потоке.
Пример первого активити:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

Socket client = null;
int port = 8888;
String address = "192.168.1.23";
String coment=null;
//Conect conect = new Conect();
TextView txtconect;
Button btnEnter;
boolean c;


//выводит все элементы этого активити
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);  //подключаем лауер-файл с элементами
    //находим эти элементы по ID
    TextView tvName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvName);
    txtconect = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtConect);
    btnEnter = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnEnter);

    btnEnter.setOnClickListener(this); // присваиваем обработчик кнопкам
}

//обработчик нажатий на кнопки
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // по id определеяем кнопку, вызвавшую этот обработчик
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.btnEnter:
            btnEnter.setEnabled(false); //делаем кнопочку неактивной
            Conect();
            if (c==true){
                txtconect.setText(coment);
                //Intent intent = new Intent(this, TwoActivity.class);
                //startActivity(intent);
            }else
                btnEnter.setEnabled(true); //делаем кнопочку активной
                txtconect.setText(coment);
            break;
    }
}

void Conect(){
    //открываю новый поток
    Thread conect = new Thread (new Runnable() {
        @Override
        //то что должно запускатся в новом потоке
        public void run() {
            try {
                // создаем объект который отображает вышеописанный IP-адрес.
                InetAddress ipAddress = InetAddress.getByName(address);
                // создаем сокет используя IP-адрес и порт сервера.
                client = new Socket(ipAddress,port);
                //переменная для получение данных
                BufferedReader in  = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
                //переменная для отправки данных
                PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(),true);
                //txtconect.setText("Успешное подключение к " + address+":"+port+"...");
                coment=("Успешное подключение к " + address+":"+port+"...");
                c = true;
                //btnEnter.setEnabled(false); //делаем кнопочку неактивной
            } catch (IOException e) {
                coment=("Не удалось подключится к " + address+":"+port+" ошибка номер №: "+e);
                c = false;
                //txtconect.setText("Не удалось подключится к " + address+":"+port+" ошибка номер №: "+e);
            }
        }
    });
    conect.start(); //запуск нового потока
}
```

Когда я нажимаю первый раз кнопочку, то btnEnter.setEnabled(false); не срабатывает и кнопочка все равно активна.
txtconect.setText(coment); тоже не обновляется. При этом мой сервер мне выдает что клиент подключен.
Потом я еще раз нажимаю на кнопочку, тогда уже срабатывает btnEnter.setEnabled(false); и txtconect.setText(coment); тоже обновляется. Но при этом мой сервер выдает мне сообщение что еще один клиент подключен. Т.е. как я понимаю уже существует два разных потока, подключенных к серверу.

Вопрос 1. Подскажите, что я делаю не так в этом случае?

Вопрос 2. Я дописал открытие второго активити после конекта:

```
if (c==true){
                txtconect.setText(coment);
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, TwoActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
```

Как сделать так, что бы кнопка НАЗАД (стрелочка влево на андроид устройстве) не возвращала меня в начальное активити, а выдавала диалог, типа "Вы точно хотите покинуть программу?"

Вопрос 3. Когда я положил телефон и курю, а потом вспомнил о нем, то экран телефона погас. Как сделать, что бы когда я активирую экран, то приложение не "сворачивалось" в память, а сразу открывалось, но не заново запускать, а продолжать работать с того места.

Вопрос 4. Как правильно отправлять и принимать информацию с сервера в других активити, т.е. как правильно обратится к:

```
BufferedReader in  = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
                //переменная для отправки данных
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(),true);
```

с других активити. Если я что то не так делаю или не так понял суть потоков в Java, объясните пожалуйста новичку.

Жду Ваших комментариев и помощи, заранее примного благодарен.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Когда вы инициируете процедуру подключения Conect() вы создаете новый поток, в котором производите подключение. При этом не дождавшись окончания процедуры подключения вы сразу же проверяете переменную if (c==true) что не правильно. Она еще не успела измениться другим потоком.

Менять текст кнопки нужно в методе Conect(), сразу после того как вы присвоили переменой coment новое значение. Соответственно, в таком случае переменная c вообще не нужна

примерно так

```
void Conect(){
//открываю новый поток
Thread conect = new Thread (new Runnable() {
    @Override
    //то что должно запускатся в новом потоке
    public void run() {
        try {
            // создаем объект который отображает вышеописанный IP-адрес.
            InetAddress ipAddress = InetAddress.getByName(address);
            // создаем сокет используя IP-адрес и порт сервера.
            client = new Socket(ipAddress,port);
            //переменная для получение данных
            BufferedReader in  = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
            //переменная для отправки данных
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(),true);
            //txtconect.setText("Успешное подключение к " + address+":"+port+"...");
            coment=("Успешное подключение к " + address+":"+port+"...");
            txtconect.setText(coment);
            //Intent intent = new Intent(this, TwoActivity.class);
            //startActivity(intent);
            //btnEnter.setEnabled(false); //делаем кнопочку неактивной
        } catch (IOException e) {
            coment=("Не удалось подключится к " + address+":"+port+" ошибка номер №: "+e);
            btnEnter.setEnabled(true); //делаем кнопочку активной
            txtconect.setText(coment);
            //txtconect.setText("Не удалось подключится к " + address+":"+port+" ошибка номер №: "+e);
        }
    }
});
conect.start(); //запуск нового потока
```

}

2) нужно переписать метод

```
/**
 * нажатие кнопки
 */
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown( final int keycode, final KeyEvent e )
{
    if( keycode ==keycode.KEYCODE_BACK )
    {
        /// тут вопрос про выход
    }

    return super.onKeyDown( keycode, e );
}
```

4) если вам надо получить информацию с сервера в нескольких активити, то возможно стоит пересмотреть концепцию всего приложения.

Например сделать так, чтобы за обмен информацией отвечал сервис. А активити уже общались с сервисом через "свои каналы". каналов обмена информацией между акитиви и сервисом много. Более подробно вы можете узнать, изучив [ряд статей](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom.html).

Comment: может тогда создать отдельный класс, который в новом потоке подключится к серверу?

Comment: Грамотнее всего создать отдельный класс с методом, который будет в качестве параметра принимать так называемую callback функцию. в которой вы можете описать все действия в случае удачного или неудачного соединения.

Comment: ответ на первый вопрос не работает, я так сразу пробовал. Выскакивает ошибка приложение и оно закрывается. Т.е. в новом потоке нельзя обновлять View. И еще я на другую кнопку присвоил отправку сообщения на сервер, что тоже повело за собой ошибку и закрытия.